# How to always return login/sign in view when I'm unauthorized in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I've a problem with the implementation of the functionality which always returns view to sign in when I'm unauthorized. My project is created in ASP.NET CORE MVC 3.1 with JWT Bearer. I can sign in when I go to the view Login.cshtml directly (after click Sign In), and then my methods with [Autorize] attribute working fine.
I'd like to always return view to sign in, when I go to the method with [Authorize] attribute.

I've found some examples with cookie which return sign in view, but I'm using JWT Bearer with Session and I don't know it's necessary. Thank's in advance for help.

Answer (score 2):

Finnally I found way which working in .NET Core 3.1. This code redirect to login/signIn page when status code is 401 - unauthorized.

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
   var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
   var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

   if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
   {
    response.Redirect("/Home/Login?returnUrl=" + request.Path);
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call an API with authorize attribute, if the bearer token is expired you must be returning 401 - Unauthorized error code to the caller. As soon as you get a 401 error code, you can redirect to sign-in page with your frontend logic only.

Comment: I use .cshtml view in my project, and I think about adding logic like this:

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/SignIn"));

Comment: @kamil, Your code of redirect is not working. I test it.